# What does こっちも mean here?

Tags: translation, meaning

Of course, こっちも can be "me too," etc. but that doesn't seem to fit here. Here is one line I've seen, though there are plenty of examples of this usage.

> あんたの力になりたいのは山々だが、こっちも金を持ってないやつの力にはなりたくないんだ

If I had to say, I think the import of the line is "I really want to help you, but I don't want to help a guy without money." Where does こっちも come in? The meaning of "also" doesn't make sense, as there is no one around in the context of the line. I guess it could mean even? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The も indicates "like everybody else", or indicates "like you have interests, we have interests, too". Which one it is is not clear here.

An example of the former that's more clear: `こんな臭いもん、私たちも食べられない`
Latter: `あんたもしんどいだろうが、こっちもしんどいんだ`

So in your case it's possibly either: `I really want to help you, but I don't want to help a guy without money (like everybody else doesn't)` or `I really want to help you, but like you have interests I have interests, too. I don't want to help a guy without money`